# Convert Multiline Excel Data into column and rows using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am looking to reshape the data from an excel sheet using Python. This is how my data looks

```
AuditDate      Fields                     ModifiedBy
1/1/2019 7:58  Status: Assigned  (0)                
               Site Group: XXX                      
               Region: xxx                          
               Site: xxxxx                          
               Summary: xxxx                        
               Location Company: xxx                
               Support Organization: XXXX           
               Support Group Name: xxxxx            
               Last Name: xxxx                      
               First Name: xxxx                     
               Categorization Tier 1:               
               Categorization Tier 2:               
               Categorization Tier 3:               
               Company: xxxx                        
               Priority: xxx                        
               Work Order Type: xxx                 
               Company3: xxxxx                      
               Request Manager:                     
               Product Cat Tier 1(2):               
               Product Cat Tier 2 (2):              
               Product Cat Tier 3 (2):              
               ASORG: IT Shoreside                  
               ASCPY: xxxx                          
               ASGRP: xxx                           
               Request Assignee:                    
               Status History: XXXX       XXXX           
1/1/2019 8:31  Request Assignee: XXXX     XXXX      
1/1/2019 15:02 Status: Pending  (1)       XXXX      
1/3/2019 13:00 Status: Completed  (5)     XXXX      
1/9/2019 2:46  Status: Closed  (8)        XXXX
```

So if you see above the the first row is a multiline where data before colon(:)   is to converted to columns.

Among here from FieldsChanged I am just concerned with Status, Priority, Request Assignee and ASGRP which i want to convert into columns. The output result will look like this

```
AuditDate       Status     Priority RequestAssignee ASGRP ModifiedBy
1/1/2019 7:58   Assigned   XX       XXX             XXX   XXXX
1/1/2019 8:31                       XXXX                  XXXX
1/1/2019 15:02  Pending                                   XXXX
1/3/2019 13:00  Completed                                 XXXX
1/9/2019 2:46   Closed                                    XXXX
```

The same data can be present in other rows as well. After reshaping the data this is how excel should look.

I would greatly appreciated if someone can help

Comment: There are two different problems here: how to read an excel sheet, and how to process the data. The first part depends on what additional modules you can use - the default would be to export the sheet in CSV format and then use the standard library csv module. You will need non standard packages to directly read an Excel file (pandas, pyxls). The latter part is rather simple Python code but depend on the former. TL/DR: is it possible to process a CSV export instead of a binary Excel file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Yes we can use csv too. I know about module we can use to read excel. But I have problems with second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the sheet has been converted to a csv file. So, you can use the csv module to first parse the rows and then parse the `Fields` field. And you can directly use the same csv module to directly build the result csv file.

Assuming that the input csv file is (note the quotes around the multiline field):

```
AuditDate,Fields,ModifiedBy
1/1/2019 7:58,"Status: Assigned (0)
Site Group: XXX
Region: xxx
Site: xxxxx
Summary: xxxx
Location Company: xxx
Support Organization: XXXX
Support Group Name: xxxxx
Last Name: xxxx
First Name: xxxx
Categorization Tier 1:
Categorization Tier 2:
Categorization Tier 3:
Company: xxxx
Priority: xxx
Work Order Type: xxx
Company3: xxxxx
Request Manager:
Product Cat Tier 1(2):
Product Cat Tier 2 (2):
Product Cat Tier 3 (2):
ASORG: IT Shoreside
ASCPY: xxxx
ASGRP: xxx
Request Assignee:
Status History: XXXX",XXXX
1/1/2019 8:31,Request Assignee: XXXX,XXXX
1/1/2019 15:02,Status: Pending (1),XXXX
1/3/2019 13:00,Status: Completed (5),XXXX
1/9/2019 2:46,Status: Closed (8),XXXX
```

You can easily process it that way:

```
with open('input.csv', newline='') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd)       # directly use a DictReader for reading
    # declare a DictWriter for the required fields ignoring any additional field (extrasaction)
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, ['AuditDate', 'Status', 'Priority', 'Request Assignee',
                                'ASGRP', 'ModifiedBy'], extrasaction='ignore')
    wr.writeheader()               # write the headers
    for row in rd:
        with io.StringIO(row['Fields']) as ffd:     # process Fields
            frd = csv.reader(ffd,delimiter=':', skipinitialspace=True)
            row.update(dict(frd))  # update the row dictionary with the "sub-fields"
        _ = wr.writerow(row)       # and directly use that
```

You should get as expected:

```
AuditDate,Status,Priority,Request Assignee,ASGRP,ModifiedBy
1/1/2019 7:58,Assigned (0),xxx,,xxx,XXXX
1/1/2019 8:31,,,XXXX,,XXXX
1/1/2019 15:02,Pending (1),,,,XXXX
1/3/2019 13:00,Completed (5),,,,XXXX
1/9/2019 2:46,Closed (8),,,,XXXX
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
This is helpful. I am just getting an error with Fields. Is there any specific module you are using. This is the error
with io.StringIO(row['Fields']) as ffd:     # process Fields
KeyError: 'Fields'

Comment: @AbdulShaikh: I am using the `io` module here.

Comment: I am using io and csv module already but still I am getting this error

Comment: @AbdulShaikh It could come from the way your csv file has been  build, specifically what is the actual delimiter. Could you show me the first 2 lines as text and not from Excel.

Comment: I got it. It was the column name that you were using which I didnt realize earlier.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest usage of the pandas library. This follows an intuitive table style format (similar to excel)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

You can then filter and reshape the read dataframe (table) as required or drop rows with na (ie using the audit date column).

Comment: Ohk. But my concern here is how do I convert those multiline values to row headers and accordingly put data to those headers with respect to the datetime. I am considerably new to this. And cannot find any example as to how to do it.