# I am looking to reorganize the data in CSV file. CSV file has multiline fields and this is how data looks like:

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
Inc;Description;Detailed Decription;Assigned;
DCC000000002934;clusterGroupFaulted XXXXXXXXXXXX;"Host:         XX-XXXX-XXX
CI Status:      Unknown
MsgID:          XXXXXX
Object:         XXXXXXX
Event ID:           XX.XXXXXX.XXXX.3XX

https://XXXXXXX.XXXX

Tool specific:
severityId=error
Time=Tue 13 Aug 2013 01:31:31 PM CEST
Name=xx-XX-XX
Type=XXXX XXXX
SubType=Xxxxxx
State=XXXX xxxx XXXX xxx
Origin=Cluster xxxx
sName=xx-xxxx10r
ContainerName=xx-xxar-xx01
ContainerType=CLUSTER";Xxxxxx;
...
```

Thus, as you may see above the column 'Detailed Description'  has multiplie lines and I would like to convert those to columns. I'm interested only in Inc, Description, Detailed Description(MsgID:,Time=, sName=, ContainerName=) <== as new columns

I tried DictReader + StringIO but it seems I have no luck solution took from this [Convert Multiline Excel Data into column and rows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789589/convert-multiline-excel-data-into-column-and-rows-using-python)

```
>>> with open('parse3.csv', newline='') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
...     rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
...     wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, ['Inc', 'Description', 'Detailed Decription'], extrasaction='ignore')
...     wr.writeheader()
...     for row in rd:
...         with io.StringIO(row['Detailed Decription']) as ffd:
...             frd = csv.reader(ffd,delimiter='\n', skipinitialspace=True)
...             row.update(dict(frd))
...         _ = wr.writerow(row)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
KeyError: 'Detailed Decription'
>>>
```

Could someone help me with this?

After your suggestions,this is what I get now:

```
>>> with open('parse4.csv', newline='') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
...     rd = csv.DictReader(fd,delimiter=';')
...     wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, ['Incident Number', 'Description', 'Detailed Decription'], extrasaction='ignore')
...     wr.writeheader()
...     for row in rd:
...         with io.StringIO(row['Detailed Decription']) as ffd:
...             frd = csv.reader(ffd,delimiter='\n', skipinitialspace=True)
...             row.update(dict(frd))
...         _ = wr.writerow(row)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
>>> print(row)
OrderedDict([('Inc', 'DCC000000002934'), ('Description', 'clusterGroupFaulted XXXXXXXXXXXX'), ('Detailed Decription', 'Host:         XX-XXXX-XXX\nCI Status:      Unknown\nMsgID:          XXXXXX\nObject:         XXXXXXX\nEvent ID:           XX.XXXXXX.XXXX.3XX\n\nhttps://XXXXXXX.XXXX\n\nTool specific:\nseverityId=error\nTime=Tue 13 Aug 2013 01:31:31 PM CEST\nName=xx-XX-XX\nType=XXXX XXXX\nSubType=Xxxxxx\nState=XXXX xxxx XXXX xxx\nOrigin=Cluster xxxx\nsName=xx-xxxx10r\nContainerName=xx-xxar-xx01\nContainerType=CLUSTER'), ('Assigned', 'Xxxxxx'), ('', '')])
>>>
```

## #

It seems like there is a problem with delimiter. I tried to change csv to get same delimiter in column 'Detailed Description', like:

```
Inc;Description;Detailed Decription;Assigned;
DCC000000002934;clusterGroupFaulted XXXXXXXXXXXX;"severityId=error
Time=Tue 13 Aug 2013 01:31:31 PM CEST
Name=xx-XX-XX
Type=XXXX XXXX
SubType=Xxxxxx
State=XXXX xxxx XXXX xxx
Origin=Cluster xxxx
sName=xx-xxxx10r
ContainerName=xx-xxar-xx01
ContainerType=CLUSTER";Xxxxxx;
```

```
with open('parse4.csv', newline='') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd,delimiter=';')       
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, ['Inc', 'Description', 'sName', 'ContainerName'], extrasaction='ignore')
    wr.writeheader()               
    for row in rd:
        with io.StringIO(row['Detailed Description']) as ffd:
            frd = csv.reader(ffd,delimiter='=',skipinitialspace=True)
            row.update(dict(frd))
        _ = wr.writerow(row
```

and I get output as expected, but in this particular case I don't want to change source file. It seems like I need to deal with multiple delimiters ': | ='. Any idea that may help?

Comment: What, *exactly* did you try, and how *exactly* did it not work? The standard `csv` module would handle this just fine, so if you don't want this closed as a duplicate you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: added information in original post.

Comment: error shows problem in 6th line probably with `row['Detailed Decription']` so you could first use `print(row)` to see what you get.

Comment: `rd = csv.DictReader(fd)` you are using the default csv delimiter, a comma, but your delimiter is a semi-colon, i.e. `';'`.

Comment: added info in original post

Comment: This is a totally different error. Why are you doing `row.update(dict(frd))`?

Comment: to # update the row dictionary with the "sub-fields". I updated my findings in original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Detailed Description` is not in a CSV format, so using `csv.reader` to parse it won't work.  Instead, try a regular expression:

```
import csv
import re

def parse(desc):
    # split multi-line description into a list of lines
    lines = desc.splitlines()
    # Split on the first equal sign or colon and remove optional spaces afterward
    data = [re.split('(?:=|:)\s*',line,1) for line in lines]
    # Remove lines that didn't split into 2 and return remaining key/value pairs as a dictionary
    return dict([x for x in data if len(x) == 2])

with open('parse3.csv', newline='') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd,delimiter=';')
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fdout, 'Inc Description MsgID Time sName ContainerName'.split(), extrasaction='ignore')
    wr.writeheader()
    for row in rd:
        # Update row dict with additional dict parsed from multi-line field
        row.update(parse(row['Detailed Decription']))
        wr.writerow(row)
```

output.csv:

```
Inc,Description,MsgID,Time,sName,ContainerName
DCC000000002934,clusterGroupFaulted XXXXXXXXXXXX,XXXXXX,Tue 13 Aug 2013 01:31:31 PM CEST,xx-xxxx10r,xx-xxar-xx01
```